# How to delete records of main model when records of child model (created using inherits main model) deleted in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-8

In my odoo application, i have Two models. One main model and a child model.

main model

```
class main_model(models.Model):
   _name = 'main.model'
```

My child model is

```
class child_model(models.Model):
   _inherits = {
    'main.model: 'main_ref'
      }
   _name = 'child.model'

   main_ref = fields.Many2one('main.model')
```

With this coding. When i create a record in child model, a record will be created in main model also. But when i delete a record in child model corresponding record in main also should be deleted.

For this what i done is...

```
@api.multi
def unlink(self):
    self.main_ref.unlink()
    return super(child_model, self).unlink()
```

But this is not working. It is showing error as..

```
The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attribute **ondelete='cascade'** in fields definition.

```
main_ref = fields.Many2one('main.model', ondelete='cascade' )
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks it is working. Note: (It will work with both ondelete and unlink mthod)